# Developing a ViewModel to interface between WPF View and legacy non-observable data types

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to write a ViewModel in order to interface between a WPF View and a legacy code. The legacy code communicates with a piece of hardware and none of the classes implement any notification mechanism such as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for example.

```
class MyDevice{

    public byte[] memory = new byte[256];

    public MyDevice(){
    }   

    private void OnSerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        // read serial port, interpret received data then update values on memory[]
        if (some condition){
            memory[index] = newValue;
        }       
    }

}
```

The code above will update our local array of bytes according to the data received from the hardware.

Now lets say I want in my View to bind a ListView control to the content of `MyDevice.memory[]`

One possibility would be replacing the array data type by an `ObservableCollection`. However, that impacts many methods inside MyDevice, and I would rather not change them.

How can I write a ViewModel to allow such interaction, minimally affecting my legacy class?

Comment: Your `MyDevice` class could implement an event to notify about updates. This way you don't have any "ui specific" classes in your device class. Then subscribe to it on your viewmodel. If there is no way to notify about changes from your device class then you probably have to poll for changes.

Comment: Yeah I agree. So I am willing to implement some minimal notification on the Model as it is event driven by nature. But I still want to implement the requirements for binding outside of the MyDevice, i.e. within the ViewModel layer.

Comment: This is a question that gets asked constantly here, and the answer is "it depends". There's no single answer. The bottom line is you're trying to shoe-horn classes written for a very specific purpose (i.e. entity serialization) into a system with completely different requirements (change notification). Sometimes you can inject IPNC automatically at runtime (Castle Windsor), sometimes at build time (Fody PropertyChanged), and sometimes you just have to bite the bullet and write code to keep two data sets synchronized, either explicitly or automatically using reflection. Like I said, it depends.

Comment: FWIW my inclination would be to make the viewmodel a totally separate class. The change to datareceived then becomes purely publishing a change somehow. I'd make that as decoupled as possible. Pub/Sub using mvvmlight messenger or RabbitMQ if making these two things different apps is logical. This advice is based on what though?  A couple lines of example code and a vague understanding of your requirement.